# What is this (water-loving) bug?

Tags: species-identification

For some time we've been finding these little fellows in our apartment:

[image: Critter!]

They seem harmless enough, but finding them is a bit... annoying. I found the fellow above in the bathtub, and it's not uncommon to find more than one.

Unfortunately, some started to appear near the kitchen sink as well. Or outside of the bathroom on the floor (at least that's where we noticed them).

I think this thing prefers darkness over light, and seems to be drawn towards wet places or just water. These critters are also surprisingly fast.

What is it? Should we be concerned about a pest problem, or is this just a minor, unwelcome guest?

PS. We live in Poland.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a *[Lepisma saccharina](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish)* or silverfish.

It is rather common and yes, it's harmless.

Comment: This answer would get more upvotes if you added a picture and perhaps addressed why the OP is finding them in wet locations in their home. In other words, it'd be good to "beef up" your answer a bit :).

Comment: @theforestecologist While you'd generally be right, as the OP I find the Wikipedia link to be a very good answer. After reading through the Wiki article I found it not surprising at all - the bug likes wet places, darkness and is fast (all 3 characteristics that I listed). No surprises then that I find the things in the bathtub or near the sink...